# How can I re-write an equation (or system of equations) in parametric form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

For the equation $y = 3x$ I need to re-write $x$ and $y$ in terms of a variable $t$. How can I find the value of each variable in terms of $t$?

Comment: Have you tried something simple like letting $x=t$?

Comment: @chris Yes, that would work (at least in this case).

Comment: @chris In general, is it possible to re-write an equation in parametric form by letting one of the variables equal t, and then writing each variable in terms of that variable? (This seems like the most obvious solution to me, but I could be mistaken.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $y=f(x)$ is a function of $x$ we can write parametric equations by writing $x=t$ and $y=f(t)$. So in your example we write $x=t$ and $y=3t$.

Comment: Could you apply the same method to the system of equations `x = 2y, z = 3y, q = 2z`? (then y = t/2, z = 3t/2, q = 3t)?

Comment: Affirmative, and your solution y = t/2, z = 3t/2, q = 3t looks good.