# Heuristics for putting $f(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ into parametric form?

Tags: parametric

Suppose I have an implicit equation:

\begin{equation}
f(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0
\end{equation}

Which *might* be 'paramaterizable'; i.e. put it into the form:
\begin{align}
x_0 &= g_0(t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_m) \\
x_1 &= g_1(t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_m) \\
\vdots \\
x_n &= g_n(t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_m)
\end{align}

where each of the $g$ functions may be in terms of any of the parameters $t_k$ up to $t_m$, where $m \le n$.

I have two queries, which I suspect are closely related:

1. Is there a general test which can be performed to determine if parameterization is even possible? I already know from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1071937/210092) that not all curves can be parameterized, but I don't quite understand how to test this.
2. Judging by the fact that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1703984/210092) does not yet have an answer, it suggests that there is no algorithm for determining the parameterization of a function $f$. I found three examples of parameterization of specific functions on this site (a [trochoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489812/210092), [power function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/814889/210092), and [a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/234446/210092)). The first two answers use heuristics very specific to the problems in question, and the last one uses a general rule for two variables, when one can be written explicitly (when $y=f(x)$, $x=t$ and $y=f(t)$, quite trivial). So if there is no algorithm, is there a widely accepted heuristic approach to parameterization (i.e. something akin to the [LIATE rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#LIATE_rule) for integration by parts)? The more specific, the better.

Comment: If you're talking about a single parameter $t$, the parametric equation describes a curve.  Apart from singular cases, one implicit equation in $n+1$ variables will describe an $n$-dimensional variety which is not a curve unless $n=1$.

Comment: In principle, for a reasonably nice function $f$ each branch of the curve $f(x_0, x_1) = 0$ can be parametrized by arc length.  Whether there is a **closed form** parametrization is another question.

Comment: Oh, so what you're saying is there need to be additional parameters to describe higher dimensional geometries?

Comment: I guess that makes sense, I can imagine how a 3D surface would require 2 parameters to specify a location on the surface.